# Google Cloud Vision API - can it run offline?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I am developing a project to use OCR to detect texts in medical reports. The medical reports contain sensitive data and need to perform OCR offline within our system, instead of sending into google server to perform OCR in the cloud. This way is it possible to use Google Cloud Vision API?

Comment: It is possible but for some reason my answer was deleted.  https://cloud.google.com/vision/on-prem

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot run it locally.

You can send big batches of files that are processed [offline](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/batch)(on server side) in the sense that your request will be handled asynchronously, but this is not what you are searching for, right?

If you have doubts about how the data that you are sending to to API is being used, held or shared, you may have a look on their [Data Usage FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/data-usage)
or the [Data Processing and Security Terms](https://cloud.google.com/terms/data-processing-terms) that is applicable for your region.